# MSTest cancellation mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

Is there any mechanism, that provide CancellationToken (or maybe attribute like [TestInitialize]) for unit test, that can be used to understand that unit test is cancelled? I could not find.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, it should be possible to achieve this with your own Test Extension (derived from `TestClassExtensionAttribute`), which you would use instead of the standard `[TestClass]` attribute.

It's a bit challenging as it requires deployment/registration of your test extension (read ["Extending the Visual Studio Unit Test Type, part 1"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-1.aspx)).

This will give you access to the `TestExecution.OnTestStopping` event. In the event handler, you can request cancellation on a certain instance of `CancellationTokenSource`.

It's up to you how you'd make the `CancellationTokenSource.Token` available to the test method itself. E.g., you could use `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData`. In which case, you would also need to handle `TestExecution.BeforeTestInitialize` and use `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData` to store the information, required to look up the right `CancellationTokenSource`. You'd probably need to main a dictionary of `TestContext`-to-`CancellationTokenSource`, to make sure you're cancelling the right test.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: @JobaDiniz, thanks, feel free to contribute a fixed link using the Edit buttons below the answer.